# Can I easily disable Crossfire?

Tags: amd-radeon, crossfire

I have a second Radeon 5850 coming, and I'd like to see the performance that the second card offers. To do this, I'd like to try the game with Crossfire, disable it, and then try it with just a single card. Can this be done easily in software, or do I need to remove the bridge or (even worse) the second card?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Head over to Catalyst Control Center, Crossfire tab & uncheck the checkmark against Crossfire.

[image]

Comment: Great. It'll perform exactly as a single card would, then? Also, I don't see that tab now. Does it get added when the second card is present?

Comment: @Mike that should be the case.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the new CCC, and still can't find that setting, but I'm sure it'll appear once the bridge is in place.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the other direction man...I've had problems disabling crossfire and SLI without uninstalling the driver and re-install.  Just saying.  That's how I got it demonstrated though.